# Simple data writer not working in non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

I have added simple data writer with timestamp in my test and its working fine when i run in UI mode. If i run the same script in non GUI mode no file is getting created.

File name

```
${__property(logFile)}${__time(MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss,)}.jtl
```

Non GUI mode command

```
C:\PerformanceTesting\Softwares\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\DynamicData\Scripts\DynamicData.jmx
```

I want to create the output file with time stamp, that's why i added simple data writer. Is this possible to create result file with timestamp in non gui mode parameter itself?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think you can build the command by powershell script to create the result file with timestamp at run time.

Comment: Yes i have a workaround, but i want to know whether its a bug or not

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, if I pass the `logFile` property via `-J` command-line argument the file with the appropriate prefix is being created. If I omit the property the file with `logFile` prefix is created.

[image]

1. Ensure that [`ApacheJMeter_functions.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions/5.5) file is present in "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries. You might want to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) if there are no messages which could help to localise the issue